# "Connection failed to 'localhost'" in VisualCron

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, visualcron

I am using VisualCron 9.9.12 (on Windows server 2016) and as of today I cannot start the VC server. I'm getting the message:

> Connection failed to 'localhost'.
>
> This may indicate that the Server has not been fully started or that Server is not running. If you just installed or started the VisualCron Server then wait a few seconds and try again.

This is what I am getting in the logs:

server_startup.txt:

> 8/8/2023 10:33:43 Debug   7Zip library path: C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualCron\7z64.dll
>
> 8/8/2023 10:33:43 Debug   Starting up
>
> 8/8/2023 10:33:43 Debug   LoadSettingsFolderFromRegistry->Settings folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualCron\settings
>
> 8/8/2023 10:33:43 Debug   Loading settings
>
> 8/8/2023 10:33:44 Err Unhandled exception: There was an error deserializing the object of type CommClientCore.Classes.CommStatistics. Unexpected end of file. Following elements are not closed: floa, ArrayOffloat, _secondMessageSize, CommStatistics. Line 1, position 251.

log_trayclient20230808.txt:

> 8/8/2023 09:36:59     Ping()->Server is null
>
> 8/8/2023 09:36:59     Ping()->Wrong exit
>
> 8/8/2023 09:36:59     Ping failed (3), service installed: True, processCount: 1
>
> 8/8/2023 09:36:59     PingCheck->Unknown failure
>
> 8/8/2023 09:36:59     Connecting to VisualCron Server
>
> 8/8/2023 09:36:59     Could not connect to server. Error: There was no endpoint listening at net.pipe://localhost/VisualCron/ that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

What can I do? Last time I had this problem I was forced by VisualCron support staff to pay for a newer licence to get a newer version, but it seems unfair, since I'm running a fairly recent version (latest is 10.1).

Thank you.

I've tried restarting the computer but it did not help.